# How to set Session Preview data for a Publication Target

Tags: core-service, experience-manager, web8.5, sdl-tridion

I am using the Core Service API. I have a Publication Target `Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PublicationTargetData` but can't seem to get any hooks into the Session Preview data (to configure XPM). The data is set in the CME, but I can't find that documented in the API docs or via inspection of the item itself. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still working with Publication Targets, you are probably still using what is now considered legacy publishing (not based on Topology Manager).

Before Topology Manager was introduced, the XPM Session Preview configuration was stored as “SiteEdit” Application Data on the Publication Targets. Application Data can be read separately using `ReadApplicationData` in the Core Service.

With Topology Manager based publishing, this information is stored in Topology Manager and Publication Targets are obsolete.

Comment: yes... using legacy... thanks for the answer. I will test tomorrow and accept once I confirm.